# Null Pointer Exception when using Button in a ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-widget, nullpointerexception

I am writing a program in which I need to use Button in each and every row in a List View, but every time I am getting Null Pointer Exception, why?

**Log says:**

```
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.example.appointment.RescheduleActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(RescheduleActivity.java:162)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1970)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:956)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:521)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:456)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:468)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:764)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1890)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:909)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2003)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-06 14:12:11.467: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 14:12:19.667: I/Process(530): Sending signal. PID: 530 SIG: 9
```

*Error Line (i.e :- 162 in ImageAdapter)*

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

**Code:**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
        }



        //  STATUS
        TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        txtStatus.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        txtStatus.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Status"));   

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sUserID = MyArrList.get(position).get("UserID").toString();
                Log.d(tag, "sAppointmentID :: " + sUserID);
                String sAppointmentID = MyArrList.get(position).get("AppointmentID").toString();
                Log.d(tag, "sAppointmentID :: " + sAppointmentID);

                Intent newActivity = new Intent(RescheduleActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("UserID", sUserID);
                newActivity.putExtra("AppointmentID", sAppointmentID);
                startActivity(newActivity);                      
            }                   
        });

        return convertView;              
    }                
}
```

Comment: Did you double check if your `buttonId` in your layout is `btnUpdate` ?

Comment: If you are pointing the right line, it's your button which is NULL. I guess you have some "id" problem. Check your "R.id.btnUpdate" id in your xml (is it well defined, and also defined as a Button?).

Comment: sorry i forgot to use convertView, thanks to njzk2, Raghunandan & klamitsuri they all has given correct answer

Comment: @Sneha also use a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance and override annotation to onclick method

Comment: @Raghunandan can you show me how my code should look like

Comment: @Sneha check the docs http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: it should be : `Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);`

Comment: Use debugger to get the point where the exception happens

Answer (score 2):

You missed the  `convertView.` when finding the button:

replace

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
```

With

```
Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late, yes i agree with *@njzk2* and *@Raghunandan*

I mean you just missed, you must need to use **convertView** in your *Adapter* like you are using for other widgets in your program,

So your code should look like this:

```
 Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it as below

```
Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
```

You are inflating a view. So use the same to `findViewById`

Also use a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the xml file for btnUpdate